# Is there a way to overwrite commander js usage information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I want to completely overwrite usage information from commander js:

```
Usage: name [options]

Options:
  -V, --version  output the version number
  -h, --help     display help for command
```

to create my own.
However, I cannot find option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the README: https://github.com/tj/commander.js

> The built-in help is formatted using the Help class. You can configure the Help behaviour by modifying data properties and methods using `.configureHelp()`, or by subclassing using `.createHelp()` if you prefer.

> .usage and .name 
> These allow you to customise the usage description in the first line of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a function `helpInformation()` in Commander returns the help content, which may help to override the whole generated help text.

I am unsure whether it is part of the public API, but it is available in commander v9.4.1 and most likely in other versions.

```js
const showCustom = process.argv.indexOf("--help") >= 0 || process.argv.indexOf("-h") >= 0
if (showCustom)
{
   const content = program.helpInformation();
   console.log(content);
   return ;
}

program.parse();
```

Comment: That works too. `.helpInformation()` was made public in Commander v5.

Comment: I had a bit of trouble overriding the help. Thank you for confirming.